# Quadruple Requires Editing Review

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I recently reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22414746) item in Triage as "Requires Editing". I was the third reviewer and completed the review. It appears that immediately *after* the review was completed, another reviewer came along and hit "Requires Editing", changing it to *four* reviews of the same type!

[image]

It seems that both me and the 4th reviewer were reviewing it at the same time, and I submitted my review first. From what I've read, there's only supposed to be one person reviewing an item at a time. It looks like, in this case, 2 users were reviewing one item at the same time.

Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There [is a 15-minute "grace period" when users can still submit reviews after the review is completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/how-is-this-user-able-to-review-posts-so-long-after-they-were-completed-original/268592#268592). This is to account for the fact that there may be multiple people reviewing the same task at the same time, and this is done to ensure that everyone who reviews the task gets credit for reviewing the item:

> We've had a "grace period" for reviews since very early in the life of the system: reviews could come in late and still be recorded, although generally without affecting the actual outcome of the task. This was done to allow for the fact that multiple people are often reviewing the same task simultaneously; while the system tries to prevent this, it does not disallow it, and in some cases having multiple simultaneous reviewers is advantageous: tasks that require multiple reviews to complete (close, reopen) can be completed more quickly if the same task is assigned to multiple reviewers at once.

(Note that in the past, the grace period was implemented in a crude way, so it was possible to modify the background HTML to force-submit reviews *long* after the review was completed. This isn't the case here, and that hole has anyway been plugged.)